# How do I get all entries in a table and put them into a string?

Tags: lua

I'm working on a ROBLOX project and I'm trying to make it so that when a player touches a brick (we'll say... a finish line!), it adds them to a table called winners.

How do I get every entry in `winners`, separate them with a comma (apart from the last one, that would look like: `test, test2, test3,` which looks weird) and then put them into one whole string to go into a StringValue in ReplicatedStorage.

Here is what I have so far:

```
...
local winners = {}
...

for _, winner in pairs(winners) do
    winnersVariable.Value = ???
end
```

Summary: Let's say I had a table (winners) with 3 objects in it (which are strings - `{"test1","test2","test3"}`). I want to extract all them strings, separate/join them with a comma and then put them into one whole string (for example: `test1, test2, test3`)

How would I do this?

Comment: `table.concat({"test1","test2","test3"},",")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either you do it manually using a loop:

```
local winners = {"Bob", "Jim", "Susanne", "John"}
local winnerList
for _, name in ipairs(winners) do
  winnerList = winnerList and winnerList .. ", " .. name or name
end
print(winnerList)
```

Or you simply use Lua's [table.concat](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-table.concat)

```
print(table.concat(winners, ", "))
```